# XSLT modify value

Tags: xslt

I have XML that I need to transform into another XML.

What I need to do is modify the value of one of the element like this. In the source I have this

```
<NUM>I19071230</NUM>
```

I need to replace the first letter with 'ABCD' which is fixed. So it will become this

```
ABCD19071230
```

Then I need to make sure the total length is 14. If it is not then add 0s between ABCD and the output should look like this.

```
ABCD0019071230
```

I need to store this value in a variable so it can be reused.
I'm using XSLT 1.0. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vComposed" select=
   "concat('ABCD',
           substring('000000000000000',
                     1,
                     14 -string-length(NUM) -3),
           substring(NUM, 2, 10)
           )
 "/>
```

**Here is a short transformation using this variable**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vComposed" select=
   "concat('ABCD',
           substring('000000000000000',
                     1,
                     14 -string-length(NUM) -3),
           substring(NUM, 2, 10)
           )
 "/>

 <xsl:value-of select="$vComposed"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<NUM>I19071230</NUM>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
ABCD0019071230
```

You can alter the length of the string value of `NUM` and verify that the correct result is produced in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try with various length of string. It works well. +1 for detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

Use this XPath expression:

```
concat(
   substring(
      'ABCD0000000000',
      1,
      15 - string-length(NUM)
   ),
   substring(NUM,2)
)
```